# How to expose Minikube cluster to internet

Tags: kubernetes, networking, minikube

I know minikube should be used for local only, but i'd like to create a test environment for my applications.
In order to do that, I wish to expose my applications running inside the minikube cluster to external access (from any device on public internet - like a 4G smartphone).

**note :** I run minikube with `--driver=docker`

**kubectl get services**

```
NAME      TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
web8080   NodePort   10.99.39.162   <none>        8080:31613/TCP   3d1h
```

**minikube ip**

```
192.168.49.2
```

One way to do it is as follows :

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=8081/tcp
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 services/web8080 8081:8080
```

then I can access it using :

```
curl localhost:8081      (directly from the machine running the cluster inside a VM)
curl 192.168.x.xx:8081   (from my Mac in same network - this is the private ip of the machine running the cluster inside a VM)
curl 84.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081 (from a phone connected in 4G - this is the public ip exposed by my router)
```

I don't want to use this solution because `kubectl port-forward` is weak and need to be run every time the port-forwarding is no longer active.

How can I achieve this ?

**(EDITED) - USING LOADBALANCER**

when using `LoadBalancer` type and `minikube tunnel`, I can expose the service only inside the machine running the cluster.

**kubectl get services**

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
my-service   LoadBalancer   10.111.61.218   10.111.61.218   8080:31831/TCP   3d3h
```

`curl 10.111.61.218:8080` (inside the machine running the cluster) is working
but `curl 192.168.x.xx:8080` (from my Mac on same LAN) is not working

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Minikube` as a development tool for a single node Kubernetes cluster provides inherent isolation layer between Kubernetes and the external devices (being specific the **inbound** traffic to your cluster from `LAN`/`WAN`).

Different [--drivers](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) are allowing for flexibility when it comes to the place where your Kubernetes cluster will be spawned and how it will behave network wise.

> A side note (workaround)!
>
> As your `minikube` already resides in a `VM` and uses `--driver=docker` you could try to use `--driver=none` (you will be able to `curl VM_IP:NodePort` from the `LAN`). It will spawn your Kubernetes cluster directly on the `VM`.
>
> Consider checking it's documentation as there are some certain limitations/disadvantages:
>
> - *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Drivers: None](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/)*

---

As this setup is already basing on the `VM` (with unknown hypervisor) **and the cluster is intended to be exposed outside of your LAN**, I suggest you going with the production-ready setup. This will inherently eliminate the connectivity issues you are facing. Kubernetes cluster will be provisioned directly on a `VM` and not in the `Docker` container.

Explaining the `--driver=docker` used: It will spawn a container on a host system with Kubernetes inside of it. Inside of this container, `Docker` will be used once again to spawn the necessary `Pods` to run the Kubernetes cluster.

As for the tools to provision your Kubernetes cluster you will need to chose the option that suits your needs the most. **Some** of them are the following:

- *[Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/)*
- *[Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray)*
- *[MicroK8S](https://microk8s.io/)*

After you created your Kubernetes cluster on a `VM` you could forward the traffic from your router directly to your `VM`.

---

Additional resources that you might find useful:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions Expose Kubernetes cluster to the Internet (Virtualbox with minikube)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559281/expose-kubernetes-cluster-to-internet/62697373#62697373)*

Comment: thanks Dawid, i'll try the kubeadm solution

Answer (score 2):

`curl $(minikube ip):$NODE_PORT` : Now we can test that the app is exposed outside of the cluster using curl, the IP of the Node and the externally exposed port.

For you : `curl 192.168.49.2:31613`

Comment: yes this works when i'm on the machine running the cluster, but i'd like to do the same from a smartphone using 4G or another device on public internet.  
I can make it work using `kubectl port-forwarding` but would like a more robust solution

Comment: thanks for the response, I've managed to have :    
`NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
my-service   LoadBalancer   10.111.61.218   10.111.61.218   8080:31831/TCP   3d3h`

and can access it using curl `10.111.61.218:8080` from the machine running the cluster, but same issue, how to expose this service to the public internet ?
when doing `curl 192.168.x.xx:8080` from another local machine, it is not exposed.

another way to ask the question, how to have the LoadBalancer get an external public ip ?

Comment: basically external ip is provided by any cloud service provider, you need to have an account in any cloud service provider. Another thing I got, does it help, have a [look](https://itnext.io/expose-local-kubernetes-service-on-internet-using-ngrok-2888a1118b5b)

Comment: thanks for the link, I read it few minutes ago and will give it a try, I think it works like `kubectl port-forwarding` but may be more efficient :)

Comment: quick feedback : `ngrok` allows you to "host" your `{minikube-ip}:{node-port}` on a random public DNS name, for example `http://6fc4fc83dd61.ngrok.io` using the command `ngrok http {minikube-ip}:{node-port}`.  

be careful, you have limited connections per minute etc, see the Pricing on ngrok website

Comment: not really the perfect solution because for each new deployment, you have to run again the command to expose your service through `ngrok` :(

Answer (score 2):

Use nginx reverse-proxy
https://www.zepworks.com/posts/access-minikube-remotely-kvm/

install nginx, then in nginx.conf add this

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 8081;
        proxy_pass  192.168.49.2:8080;
    }
}
```

restart nginx

Comment: This works!, just correcting the answer syntactically, before the ip, append http:// , remove stream {} and add the proxy_pass statement like this ,  "location / { proxy_pass 192.168.49.2:8080}"

Answer (score 0):

One way that I use to get around the fact that the process of kubectl port-forward stops after a while is to create a detach session using tmux following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session). With that, I haven't had any problems with the exact same Minikube cluster configuration that you have.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Apache's Reverse proxy rules to achieve the same as below:

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyVia Full

ProxyPass / http://192.168.59.110/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.59.110/

The complete scenario (for a bare-metal machine) is available [here](https://zubair-teach.github.io/posts/ingress-into-baremetal-minikube/) for review and can be replicated for understanding.