# Accessing a remote minikube from a local computer

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, remote-access, minikube

I'm trying to follow this guide in order to set up a cluster that I can connect to from another local machine: [https://faun.pub/accessing-a-remote-minikube-from-a-local-computer-fd6180dd66dd#:~:text=You%20can%27t%20access%20minikube,forward%20them%20to%20kube-apiserver](https://faun.pub/accessing-a-remote-minikube-from-a-local-computer-fd6180dd66dd#:%7E:text=You%20can%27t%20access%20minikube,forward%20them%20to%20kube-apiserver).

I have another VM on the same ESXI that I want to connect to the other host VM's cluster.

I managed to reach the point in the guide when the browser asks me for credentials.

When I run minikube ip I get the address 192.168.49.2.
Why when I try to access https://192.168.49.2:8443 I get connection timed out?

On the other VM I fail to reach the cluster IP because it's not on the same network. So how does that make sense?

What am I doing wrong?

I tried following the guide word to word.

I'm expecting to have a cluster that I can connect to from other VMs.

Answer (score 0):

you need to expose your minikube to hanlde all your dockers in local networks
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/
you can check this post
[How to expose Minikube cluster to internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66088041/how-to-expose-minikube-cluster-to-internet)